# Getting Wordpress category name from post ID not working

Tags: php, wordpress

The problem is that I cannot display the category of a post:

http://screencast.com/t/hdQjpSV0Q

I have the following code in a `function.php` file:

```php
// GET FEATURED IMAGE
function ST4_get_featured_image($post_ID) {
    $custom_meta = get_post_custom(get_the_ID());
    return $custom_meta["lumen_portfolio_preview_image_image"][0];
}
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'ST4_columns_head');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', ('ST4_columns_content'), 10, 2);

// ADD NEW COLUMN
function ST4_columns_head($defaults) {

    $defaults['featured_image'] = 'Featured Image';
    $defaults['categories_portfolio'] = 'Category';
    return $defaults;
}

// SHOW THE FEATURED IMAGE
function ST4_columns_content($column_name, $post_ID) {

    if ($column_name == 'featured_image') {
        $post_featured_image = ST4_get_featured_image($post_ID);
        if ($post_featured_image) {
            echo '<img style="width:300px;height:200px;" src="' . $post_featured_image . '" />';
        }
    }
    elseif ($column_name == 'categories_portfolio') {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'category' ); 
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'category' );
                if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
                    continue;
                echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        } 
    }
}
```

I have empty results, NULL, but I want to have the post category field. I used many wordpress functions, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that your using the $post->ID as your parameter in your get_the_terms function, anyways I assume that the problem is you can't retrieve the category of the post, I would recommend using the [get_the_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category#Examples) function in place of the get_the_terms in your code:

```
// SHOW THE FEATURED IMAGE
function ST4_columns_content($column_name, $post_ID) {

    if ($column_name == 'featured_image') {
        $post_featured_image = ST4_get_featured_image($post_ID);
        if ($post_featured_image) {
            echo '<img style="width:300px;height:200px;" src="' . $post_featured_image . '" />';
        }
    }
    elseif ($column_name == 'categories_portfolio') {
        //replace this $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'category' );
        $terms = get_the_category($post_ID); //should you be using this instead of $post->ID?
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            //replace this $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'category' );
                 $term_link = get_category_link($term->term_id);
                if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
                    continue;
                echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        } 
    }
}
```

You can do a `var_dump($terms)` to further see the values being returned by this function, hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: Your solution  giving me  empty results.    [link]http://screencast.com/t/KZB9RNtKPDW  i would like to display this  in the category column here: [link]http://screencast.com/t/t9FwaEIyjV3f  at these moment, i show there sign: waiting

Comment: Have you checked if you are actually passing values to your `$post_ID` parameter in your function?, and did you do a `var_dump($terms)` to check what values are being returnd

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using custom post type "Portfolio" as shown in attached screenshot.

Use `wp_get_post_terms` rather than `get_the_terms`

Update following code:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'category' );
```

to

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID , 'category', array("fields" => "all") );
```

Note that 2nd parameter is the taxonomy name you are using while registering taxonomy.

See an example below where 'testimonials-cat' is used to register taxonomy.

```
register_taxonomy('testimonials-cat', 'testimonials', $args);
```

Your code for above taxonomy will be:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->id, 'testimonials-cat', array("fields" => "all"));
```

Comment: exactly Manesh :) I was  looking for categories, but didnt look on taxonomies.  and Taxonomies was holding categories ;)